# How to get the Total of current tabs in TabLayoutPanel?

Tags: gwt

We have `tabLayoutPanel.selectTab(1)` to select the the 2nd tab of the `tabLayoutPanel`
However, we need to make sure that the `tabLayoutPanel` must currently have 2 tabs otherwise it will have "`out of bound`" error.

And if it has "`out of bound`" error & the rest of the code will not be implemented.

But there is no `getTotalTabs` method in `tabLayoutPanel`

do we need to get the Tab header and found the total tabs from the tab header?
How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't `getWidgetCount()` return what you need?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: It does. The interrogative form is rhetorical.

Answer (score 0):

[getWidgetCount()](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/TabLayoutPanel.html#getWidgetCount()) is the method you're searching for